# cannot link boost regex into mingw

Tags: boost, mingw, static-linking

my mingw compiler: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.7.2/32-bit/threads-posix/sjlj/x32-4.7.2-release-posix-sjlj-rev6.7z

boost: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.52.0/boost_1_52_0.7z

(both on D: drive)

code:

```
#include <boost\regex.hpp>
int main() {
  boost::regex reg("[a-z]+");
}
```

command line:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;D:\mingw\bin;D:\mingw\include
g++ -I "d:\mingw\include" -I "d:\boost" -Os -s -o test.exe test.cpp -std=c++11 -static -L "D:\boost\stage\lib" -lboost_regex
```

In the `d:\boost\stage\lib` directory there is `libboost_regex-mgw47-mt-1_52.a`.

And the process returns :

```
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_regex
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I put the exact name of the *.a file the result is `cannot find -llibboost_regex-mgw47-mt-1_52.a`

even whole path that is `-ld:\boost\stage\lib\libboost_regex-mgw47-mt-1_52.a` doesn't work. Whatever I put after the `-l` has the same effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_17.html) you must use either (`-l` followed by the named of the library removing the lib preffix and the extension .a):

```
g++ -I "d:\mingw\include" -I "d:\boost" -Os -s -o test.exe test.cpp -std=c++11 -static -L "D:\boost\stage\lib" -lboost_regex-mgw47-mt-1_52
```

or (full path of the library without using `-l`):

```
g++ -I "d:\mingw\include" -I "d:\boost" -Os -s -o test.exe test.cpp -std=c++11 -static D:/boost/stage/lib/libboost_regex-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
```

PS:One thing I personally do is build boost using `--layout=tagged`. This makes the name of the libraries a lot more manageable (in this case `libboost_regex-mt.a`).